# Handling mouse over on NSCell (NSTextAttachmentCell)

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, nscell

Can't figure out how to handle mouse move over `NSCell` (or `NSTextAttachmentCell`). Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a tracking area in the view that contains the cell and implement mouseEntered: and mouseExited: (and mouseMoved if you need that also) in that view. Here is an example where I added a tracking area one a button (button is the IBOutlet for the button).  I added this code in the view's awakeFromNib method:

```
NSTrackingArea *buttonArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:self.button.frame options:NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited|NSTrackingMouseMoved|NSTrackingActiveInActiveApp owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:buttonArea];
```

This will cause the view to receive mouseEntered, mouseMoved, and mouseExited messages when the cursor enters the frame of the button.

Comment: Thank you! Seems that this is only possible workaround to track nscell area.

Comment: What about a IKImageBrowserCell which is not inheriting from a NSCell, but NSObject ? thanks

Comment: @Patrick, sorry, I don't know anything about IKImageBrowserCell.